# ios push notifications certificate has no associated key

Tags: ios, certificate, push-notification

I want to create an iOS app that uses push notifications. The notifications will be triggered by a PHP webservice. To do this I needed to create an iOS push services certificate in the iOS provisioning profile (that needs to be added to the webservice to work). I downloaded the certificate and added it to keychain access.

The documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html says:

1. Open Keychain Access utility and click the My Certificates category in the left pane.
2. Find the certificate you want to install and disclose its contents.
   You'll see both a certificate and a private key.

I did exactly this, and I found the certificate in the right place, but there is no key associated with it. Where did I probably go wrong, why is there no key and how can I fix the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Okay, after completely deleting everything and re-doing all the steps it now works. I still have no idea where I did go wrong, but apparently I did somewhere.
If anybody feels like my question is not worth keeping as it apparently was not a "real" problem, feel free to delete my post.

Comment: Get the same issue. Damn apple and its certificates